# How can I set a folder icon to a jpeg image?

Tags: c++, windows, icons, directory, jpeg

I want to set a folders icon to a jpeg image. I looked into using the desktop.ini file, but it seems that that only supports icon files or files which contain icons. I dont want to use icon files because the folder icons are going to be changing a lot. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a programming question. It better suits superuser

Comment: @KenWhite well, i want a programmatic way to do this in c++. I can edit files (like desktop.ini) in c++ but I cant 'right click, properties, etc.) so i think that it does belong here

Answer (score 0):

Convert jpg to ico, use converter (for e.a. http://www.coolutils.com/online/image-converter/). You can use http://eng.softq.org/folderico_xp